# Can you add an If Statement in a LINQ(XML) query?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I feel this function is too long. I can separate it into two functions, but I would prefer to keep them in one for this.

```
Public Function getTempList(ByVal applicationType As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim doc As XDocument = New XDocument


    If My.Settings.sortKey = "alpha" Then
        Dim XMLquery = From c In doc.<applications>.<app> _
           Where c.<appFav>.Value = "true" And c.<appType>.Value = applicationType
           Order By CStr(c.<appName>.Value)
           Select c.<appName>
        Dim tempList As New List(Of String)
        For Each result In XMLquery
            tempList.Add(result.Value)
        Next
        Return tempList
    ElseIf My.Settings.sortKey = "fav" Then ' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
        Dim XMLquery = From c In doc.<applications>.<app> _
           Where c.<appFav>.Value = "true" And c.<appType>.Value = applicationType
           Order By CInt(c.<appClick>.Value) Descending
           Select c.<appName>
        Dim tempList As New List(Of String)
        For Each result In XMLquery
            tempList.Add(result.Value)
        Next
        Return tempList
    End If

End Function
```

Can I somehow put the if statement in the LINQ query itself. The only thing that needs to change here is the order the list is in. Or, is there another way to order the results I am returning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be the simplest:

```
Public Function getTempList(ByVal applicationType As String) As List(Of String)

    Dim doc As XDocument = New XDocument

    Dim XMLquery = _
        From c In doc.<applications>.<app> _
        Where c.<appFav>.Value = "true" And c.<appType>.Value = applicationType _
        Select c

    If My.Settings.sortKey = "alpha" Then
        XMLquery = XMLquery.OrderBy(Function(c) CStr(c.<appName>.Value))
    ElseIf My.Settings.sortKey = "fav" Then
        XMLquery = XMLquery.OrderByDescending(Function(c) CInt(c.<appClick>.Value))
    End If

    Return XMLquery.Select(Function(x) x.<appName>.Value).ToList()

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 Public Function getTempList(ByVal applicationType As String) As List(Of String)
        Dim doc As XDocument = New XDocument
        Dim XMLquery = From c In doc.<applications>.<app> _
              Where c.<appFav>.Value = "true" And c.<appType>.Value = applicationType
              Select c
        Dim tempList As New List(Of String)

        If My.Settings.sortKey = "alpha" Then

            XMLquery = XMLquery.OrderBy(Function(c) CStr(c.<appName>.Value))

        ElseIf My.Settings.sortKey = "fav" Then

            XMLquery = XMLquery.OrderByDescending(Function(c) CInt(c.<appClick>.Value))

        End If

        For Each result In XMLquery
            tempList.Add(result.<appName>.Value)
        Next
        Return tempList
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to repeat the whole query.

You can do something like:

Pardon me for VB syntax, I usually code in C#.

```
Public Function getTempList(ByVal applicationType As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim doc As XDocument = New XDocument
    Dim tempList As New List(Of String)

    Dim XMLquery = From c In doc.<applications>.<app> _
       Where c.<appFav>.Value = "true" And c.<appType>.Value = applicationType
       Select c.<appName>

    If My.Settings.sortKey = "aplha" Then
        Order XMLQuery By CStr(c.<appName>.Value)   // convert to VB code

    If My.Settings.sortKey = "fav" Then
        Order XMLQuery By CInt(c.<appClick>.Value) Descending //convert to VB code

    For Each result In XMLquery
        tempList.Add(result.Value)
    Next

    Return tempList
End Function
```